# How to write a file owned by root in C?

Tags: c, file-permissions, fopen, user-permissions

How can I to write into a file owned by root, for example in /etc ?
In particular I need to have the executable owned by a normal user therefore I can't run it as root nor call it with sudo.

I know this is not a specific C problem, however I'd like to know a possible solution in C.
The same solution in another language may help as well.

Example using a C programming language

```
/*
 How can I write into a file owned by root user?

 -rwxrwxr-x  1 user user 8480 ott 17 11:48 test
 -rw-rw-r--  1 user user  432 ott 17 11:48 test.c
 -rw-rw-r--  1 root root   20 ott 17 11:48 textfile.txt

 $ ./test 
Test how to write a file owned by root
File can't be opened
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Test how to write a file owned by root\n");

    FILE *fp;
 
    fp = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
 
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "Wite success!\n");
        printf("\n Details successfully written to the file\n\n");
    }
    else
        printf("File can't be opened\n");
 
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not a C problem (if you can solve it in Java, or BASIC, or any other language apply that same solution to C).

Comment: I know this is not a specific C problem, however I'd like to know a possible solution in C.
The same solution in another language may help as well.

Comment: Unrelated: `fprintf(fp, "Wite success!\r\n");` has 1 `'\r'` too many. Since you opened the file in `"w"` (text) mode, the `fwrite()` will do the correct Windows thing and write `"\r\n"` when it sees `"\n"` giving you an end result of `"...success!\r\r\n"` on disk. If you're on Linux, then `"\r\n"` is correct for writing a Windows file... but then you should have opened the file in binary mode (`"wb"`).

Comment: That is not a programming problem at all. You will need to set privileges for the executable, no matter what language you used to create it. This is just a Linux issue. Might be better suited on SuperUser stack

Comment: How can you break the rules and get away with it? You can't.